# ArcObjects: How to remove a custom layer?

Tags: arcobjects, c++, arcscene

How is a custom layer supposed to be destructed?
I have a custom layer that implements drawing by overriding IActiveViewEvents::AfterDraw.
The problem is that sometimes when the custom layer is removed from the Scene/Table Of Contents it is still drawn!?

The FinalRelease() method is never called in my custom layer.

1. I would expect it to be ArcScenes responsibility to delete my custom layer when it is removed?; which in turn would call my FinalRelease() method.
2. If my custom layer is not in the Scene/Table Of Contents; how comes it receives IActiveViewEvents::AfterDraw calls?
   I would expect ArcScene to draw only layers in the Scene/Table Of Contents.

Here is an overview of my code:

```
    class ATL_NO_VTABLE MyLayer :
    public ILayer,
    public IGeoDataset,
    public IGraphicsContainer3D,
    public IActiveViewEvents,
    public IPersistVariant, .... 
    {

    public:
    HRESULT FinalConstruct()
    {
        return S_OK;
    }

    void FinalRelease() // newer called!
    {
        return S_OK;
    }

    // called after layer has been removed!?
    STDMETHOD(AfterDraw)(IDisplay * Display, esriViewDrawPhase phase); 

    ...
    };


    HRESULT addMyLayer() // called by user clicking a button
    {
      IMyLayerPtr myLayer(CLSID_MyLayer);
      IApplicationPtr ipApp(CLSID_AppRef); 
      IDocumentPtr doc;
      ipApp->get_Document(&doc)
      if(doc)
        return S_FALSE;
      ISxDocumentPtr sxdoc;
      sxdoc = doc;
      if(!sxdoc)
        return S_FALSE;
      IScenePtr scene;
      sxdoc->get_Scene(&scene);
      if(!scene)
            return S_FALSE;
      return scene->AddLayer(myLayer, VARIANT_FALSE); // I add the layer, but who removes it?
    }
```

Thanks in advance for any answers!
Andreas

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: I have added parts of my code.

Comment: Custom layers are not supposed to do their drawing via handling AfterDraw. Did you consider implementing ILayer.Draw instead?

Comment: Yes but that is only called once. I need to refresh my layer graphics when the rest of the graphics in the scene is refreshed. I think calling AfterDraw is quite common. E.g. see: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/57698/can-custom-map-tiles-be-properly-rendered-via-arcobjects-within-my-arcgis-10-1-d